# android上でpythonファイルをえらんで実行できるよなアプリが作りたい

Tags: python, android

qpythonでpythonが実行できるのは分かったのですが、qpythonを介する必要があり、少々不便です。

何が言いたいか伝わりにくいかもしれませんが、スマホアプリとしてpythonを実行するようなものが作りたいのですが、なかなかいい方法が見つかりません。

kiviは使いたくありません
htmlとjavascriptを使用した環境も使いたくありません。

ほかになにかいい方法はないでしょうか？

Answer (score -2):

ーーーーーーーーーーーーーーー
termuxを使うことにしました。
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux&hl=ja
ーーーーーーーーーーーーーーー